# apache ignite database location with multiple nodes

Tags: database, distributed-computing, ignite

I am new to apache ignite and I am wondering in case we want to create a persistent database , where will the database will be stored in case we are starting multiple nodes on several servers?
Do the Schema and all data will be replicated across the system?

Answer (score 1):

Please see [the documentation on partitioning](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/data-modeling/data-partitioning).

In short, `REPLICATED` caches are replicated on all nodes, `PARTITIONED` are distributed between nodes automatically with zero or more backups, and you can also control affinity function to include/exclude nodes.